# enum classes MVC calling from controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

if i create my enum class in the global.ascx in MVC, is there a way i can call that class from a controller.

ie

i do this in my global.ascx class
volume myVolume = volume.Low

is there a way i can find out what i set myVolume to from a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope of variables check that it is accessable, then use

```
MvcApplication.MyEnumProperty = MvcApplication.EnumType.EnumValue
```

Note: its a standard class so the property will need to be defined as static or you could wrap in a singleton, your call, so that all controllers can reach it. Session might be a better place to store the value.